# $6.1$ LEMMA. If $\langle A,R \rangle $ is a well-ordering, then for all $x\in A, \langle A,R\rangle \ncong \langle \text{pred}(A,x,R),R\rangle .$

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

The following is from Kenneth Kunen's book *Set Theory : An Introduction to Independent Proofs*

> Whenever $R$ and $S$ are relations, and $A,B$ are sets, we say $\langle A,R\rangle \cong \langle B,S\rangle$ iff there is a bijection $f: A\rightarrow B$ such that $\forall x, y\in A \left(x Ry \iff f(x)Sf(y)\right).$ $f$ is called an *isomorphism* from $\langle A, R\rangle$ to $\langle B, S\rangle.$
>
> We say $R$ *well-orders* $A,$ or $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a *well-ordering* iff $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a total ordering and every non-empty subset of $A$ has an $R$- least element.
>
> if $x\in A,$ let $\text{pred}(A,x,R) = \{y\in A:yRx\}$
>
> $6.1$ LEMMA. If $\langle A,R \rangle $ is a well-ordering, then for all $x\in A, \langle A,R\rangle \ncong \langle \text{pred}(A,x,R),R\rangle  .$
>
> PROOF.  If $f : A \rightarrow \text{pred}(A,x,R)$ were an isomorphism, derive a contradiction by considering the $R$-least element of $\{y\in A :f(y)\ne y\}.$

So if $C =\{y\in A :f(y)\ne y\}$ has $x_0$ as it's $R$-least element then $f(C)$ has $f(x_0)$ as it's $R$-least element. We also observe that if $x\notin C$ then $f(x) = x$ which in turn implies that $f(x)\notin \text{pred}(A,x,R).$ Thus $A = C.$  Thus $x_0$ is the least element of $A$ and $f(x_0)$ is the least element of $\text{pred}(A,x,R).$ But both $A$ and $\text{pred}(A,x,R)$ should have the same least element. Hence $f(x_0)\neq x_0$ is the contradiction here.

Is this the contradiction the author speaks about?

Comment: What is the R-least element property?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Kunen doesn't define it, but I feel like it could be defined in the following way : $x_o$ is an $R$ - least element of a set $A$ if $\forall y\in A,\exists x_0\in A (x_0 R y)$

Comment: ok, but does  x_0 belongs to? It belongs to A ? And can the relation to be reflexive?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca The relation cannot be reflexive. Makes me want to rethink the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also don't understand from where you derive the "Thus $A=C$" in your question.

I would proceed as follows using the $C$ you defined.

$C$ is not empty as by hypothesis on $f$, $f(x) R x$ and therefore $x \in C$ as $R$ is irreflexive. As $R$ well-orders $A$, $C$ has a $R$-least element that we denote by $x_0$. We have $f(x_0) \neq x_0$ and  $\langle A, R \rangle$ being a total ordering, either $f(x_0) R x_0$ or $x_0 R f(x_0)$. $f(x_0) R x_0$ would be in contradiction with the definition of $x_0$.

Now if $x_0 R f(x_0)$, $\text{pred}(A,x_0,R) \subseteq \text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R)$. Let's have a look at the restriction of $f^{-1}$ to $\text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R)$:

1. $f^{-1}$ is $R$-increasing, i.e. $x R y \iff f^{-1}(x) R f^{-1}(y)$
   and one-to-one.
2. The image of $\text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R)$ under $f^{-1}$ is included in
   $\text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$.
3. The restriction of $f^{-1}$ to $\text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ is the
   identity map. Indeed, by definition of $x_0$ for $y \in
       \text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ we have $yRx_0$ and therefore $f(y) = y \iff y
       = f^{-1}(y)$.

Let's consider $z=f^{-1}(x_0)$. According to point 2. above $z R x_0$ and $z=f^{-1}(z)$ according to point 3. in contradiction with $f^{-1}$ injective.

Comment: I am not able to figure out the contradiction pertaining to $x_0Rf(x_0)$

Comment: Which step(s) are you missing in what I wrote?

Comment: So this is how I made sense of it - if $f : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is an isomorphism, then $f^{-1} : S_2 \rightarrow S_1$ is an isomorphism. Also if $f : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is an isomorphism then $f : S\subset S_1 \rightarrow \text{range}(S)$ is also an isomorphism, and hence $f^{-1} : \text{range}(S) \rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am trying to understand the part "$f^{-1}$ would be an isomorphism from  . . ."

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is correct. This is what I used to state $f^{-1}$ *would be an isomorphism from $\text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R)$ to $\text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$*.

Comment: So that means $f : \text{pred}(A,x_0,R) \rightarrow \text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R)$ is an isomorphism. I can see that range of $\text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ will be a subset of $\text{pred}(A,f(x_0),R),$ but why is it equal to it?

Comment: I added elements in my answer.

Comment: @BijeshK.S While the previous proof was correct, I was able to simplify it in the updated answer.

Comment: This is a lot more clear. Thank you for the time, Sir!